# Ошибка: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: PLS-00103: Встретился символ "/" Символ "/" опущен

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте у меня возникла ошибка:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: Строка 1, столбец 63:
>   PLS-00103: Встретился символ "/" Символ "/" опущен.

Пакет PL/SQL, который необходимо передать запросом:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept( var1, 'var2', 'var3');
END;
/
```

После нажатия на кнопку, находящейся в java frame, данные внесенные пользователем в поля: deptnoField, dnameField, locField; передаются запросом к БД Oracle моим пакетом. Я уже пробовал формировать запрос по разному никак не получается.

Образец ActionListenera для кнопки:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                dbm.executeQuery(String.format("DECLARE\n BEGIN\n SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(%s, %s, %s);\n"
                + " END;\n /", Integer.parseInt(deptnoField.getText()), dnameField.getText(), locField.getText()));
            }
        };
        addSaveButton.addActionListener(listener);
```

Дело в том что символ опущенный java при компиляции нельзя убирать из пакета(запроса).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При работе из собственных приложений `/` использовать не надо. Это специальный символ SQL-plus для разделения запросов. Серверу оракла он не нужен

Comment: спасибо большое, я сделал по другому:

Comment: `dbm.executeQuery(String.format("DECLARE\n BEGIN\n SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(%s, '%s', '%s');\n END;", deptnoField.getText(), dnameField.getText(), locField.getText()));`

Comment: Все стало работать, но выскакивает сообщение:  java.sql.SQLException: Строка SQL не является запросом

Comment: хотя данные заносятся в таблицу и отображаются в ней после переключения радиокнопок, привязанных к запросам выбора справочников

Comment: Скажем так - есть запросы - это то, что выдает результат (собственно только select). И есть ... не знаю как зовется, в общем то, что результат вернуть не может. Как в вашем случае. Например в библиотеках перла для первого есть метод `execute`, а для выполнения второго используется метод `do`. Попробуйте найти такой метод в джаве

Comment: хорошо, спасибо большое)

Comment: @СашаСеменец И кстати, попробуйте убрать из своего запроса `DECLARE\n`, начинайте просто с `BEGIN`, текущую ошибку это не исправит, но он тут особо не нужен. Да и переводы кареток вроде не нужны, хотя надо проверить

Comment: Вы полностью правы. Оставлю пожалуй так
 `dbm.executeQuery(String.format("BEGIN SCOTT.dept_pkg.Add_Dept(%s, '%s', '%s');"
                        + " END;", deptnoField.getText(), dnameField.getText(), locField.getText()));`

Comment: кстати убрал ошибку,  java.sql.SQLException: Строка SQL не является запросом

Comment: в моем классе модели подключения БД оставил пустым:
`catch (SQLException ex) {
        }`

Comment: Возможно, это не лучшее решение, однако глаз не мозолит)

Comment: @СашаСеменец Как же вы будете отлаживаться, если ошибок не увидите. Кстати, чуть погуглил ... Попробуйте для 'запросов' не возвращающих данных использовать не `executeQuery`, а просто `execute` это походу аналог моего `do`. Я же говорил, что второе они запросами не считают :)

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую, спасибо)))

Comment: @СашаСеменец Рекомендуют использовать executeUpdate: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e12137/addfunc.htm

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы прям скинули для ленивых таких как я)

Comment: я бы еще долго искал)